Manga where a girl dies in a car crash and is reincarnated as the neighbour's daughter
The manga is about a girl that went into fight with her parents because she didn't loved as much as her brother and died in a car crash and then she reincarnated as the neighbor's child that was a loving family and become her former brother's classmate she also found that her former family lived sorrowfully without her

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?

There's a webtoon called UPSHOT (H) that sound pretty similar, but the fight was about her patents neglecting the siblings

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Can you explain a bit more about the details that match as well as the ones that don't?
